# HTML 5 web page is loadign slowly how to improve performance

Tags: html

I have web page its performance is verly its taking long time to load images and other things.how to improve the loading performance.

Comment: no i dont have any public link

Comment: Try to check which Resources the slowest are (use for example Google Chrome Timeline).

Comment: I have checked my site on validator it gives 126 Errors, 13 warning(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a vague question but there are some general recommendations that can be given.

- Start by running your site through a tool like http://gtmetrix.com/ which uses YSlow from Yahoo and a custom validation engine to provide recommendations. The recommendations you will get from GT Metrix will cover 95%+ of the most common web best practices. (Not affiliated; just really like their tool).
- If your site isn't publicly available, you can use Chrome's developer tools (run an audit to get a list performance recommendations on the whole page, and also on JS and CSS interpretation times--very useful).
- Validate your document for errors using http://validator.w3.org. Even if your site isn't public, you can paste the source into the validator engine as text.
- If images are your main concern, use lazy loading techniques to only load visible content, such as the [jQuery lazy loader for images](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). Use the correct size/format for web images. Use a tool like http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/ to compress images.

### General Page Performance Factors

*From YSlow, in alphabetical order*

- Add Expires headers
- Avoid AlphaImageLoader filter
- Avoid CSS expressions
- Avoid empty src or href
- Avoid HTTP 404 (Not Found) error
- Avoid URL redirects
- Compress components with gzip
- Configure entity tags (ETags)
- Do not scale images in HTML
- Make AJAX cacheable
- Make favicon small and cacheable
- Make fewer HTTP requests
- Make JavaScript and CSS external
- Minify JavaScript and CSS
- Put CSS at the top
- Put JavaScript at bottom
- Reduce cookie size
- Reduce DNS lookups
- Reduce the number of DOM elements
- Remove duplicate JavaScript and CSS
- Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)
- Use cookie-free domains
- Use GET for AJAX requests

Comment: You could also try Yslow for firefox. 

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

Comment: @Tim Medora i f test on the given will they fix my site for this

Comment: when i am checking my site on valideat it is given 126 Errors, 13 warning(s)

Comment: These tools won't fix your site but they will give detailed recommendations. If you have specific questions about validation errors or recommendations that you don't understand, you can post a new question but make sure that you include more detail than "my site is slow".

Comment: Ok i got it thanks by fixing these issues will my sites performance look better

Comment: Validation errors are a good start but I'd suggest looking at the other performance issues too. Gzip compression, caching, and reducing the number of requests made by the page will probably give the biggest gains.

Comment: how to comprees those file which shows for Gzip compression and again i have to upload these on server

Comment: Here's an article on gzip techniques: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Comment: I have to set this compression on server how to do this and where i will find .htaccess fil